# Symfony2 Doctrine Parser error with DQL only

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am having a weird bug only with DQL, repository query works.
While both queries work in localhost when I move to prod environment:

```
    $entity = $em->getRepository('PanasonicTestEtAvisBundle:Review')->findAll();
```

This works.

```
    $entity = $em->createQuery('SELECT t.id FROM PanasonicTestEtAvisBundle:Review t')->getResult();
```

This fails with the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /home/sites_web/client/xxx/vendor/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php on line 1660
```

The line 1660 has:

```
if ($this->_isAggregateFunction($this->_lexer->lookahead['type'])) {
            return $this->AggregateExpression();
        } else {
            return $this->FunctionDeclaration();
        }
```

My log:

```
[2012-05-09 14:04:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2012-05-09 14:04:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\RouterListener::onEarlyKernelRequest". [] []
[2012-05-09 14:04:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2012-05-09 14:04:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2012-05-09 14:04:49] security.DEBUG: Read SecurityContext from the session [] []
[2012-05-09 14:04:49] security.DEBUG: Reloading user from user provider. [] []
[2012-05-09 14:04:49] security.DEBUG: Username "user" was reloaded from user provider. [] []
[2012-05-09 14:04:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2012-05-09 14:04:49] request.INFO: Matched route "review_edit" (parameters: "_controller": "Panasonic\TestEtAvisBundle\Controller\BOReviewController::editAction", "id": "1", "productid": "1", "_route": "review_edit") [] []
[2012-05-09 14:04:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\EventListener\RequestListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2012-05-09 14:04:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\Subscriber\SlidingPaginationSubscriber::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2012-05-09 14:04:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelController". [] []
[2012-05-09 14:04:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2012-05-09 14:04:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2012-05-09 14:04:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2012-05-09 14:04:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Acme\DemoBundle\ControllerListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2012-05-09 14:04:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\Controller\ControllerListener::onCoreController". [] []
```

I need to use DQL ultimately to get query to use with knp pagination bundle and for joins etc... Any help is kindly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out while using CuteFTP to transfer files to server, 1 or more files were not fully transfered, hence causing this weird bug. It works as it should now.